# Is it safer to reinstall or to upgrade?

Tags: system-installation, 17.10, do-release-upgrade, 18.04

So, I'd like to get the new 18.04 and I want to ask you guys this: is it safer for me to reinstall Ubuntu or can I just use the update manager with the "do-release-upgrade" without problems?

Comment: Yes, it is safer and faster to reinstall (almost always). If you wish to can backup your `/home` directory and after that create a **home** partition, that you connect during the installation. But you get rid of the program packages that you have installed. There are probably some old programs, that you will never use again, and it is easy to install a program package, when you need it.

Answer (score 2):

Always better to do a new install than an install by upgrade.

If you have a lot of applications downloaded, never fear. The easiest way to retain them is  first to make a text file of all apps on your system - `sudo dpkg --get-selections > MyApps.txt`. Keep this file in your Home folder, which should be backed up. Then download and install the new release.

To retrieve your apps - `sudo dpkg --get-selections < app-backup-list.txt`, `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: I find that an additional benefit of a fresh install is starting over, and reverting settings and programs I don't need, or fixing issues that had accumulated.

Comment: Typo? You don't really mean "app-backup-list.txt", do you?

Comment: Not a typo. You can call the file whatever you like. I just named it so I know what it includes.

Answer (score 1):

You'll always face problems trying the "do-release-upgrade" due to variations or customization you previously made to the version you have.
Even if you didn't change anything there is a pretty good chance to end up with a broken system after upgrade.

So a *Fresh install* is always a better option.